# Unexpected boot menu option on RHEL 9

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, grub, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have 2 SSDs on my laptop both 512gb. I have windows on one of them and today I installed RHEL for learning purpose on the other. I expected 2 options on my boot menu - one for windows and other for RHEL but I recieved 3. The third one was HDD0 then name of my SSD in which I have installed my linux. Is it normal? Click on HDD0 created another entry.
[image]

After selecting second option grub starts and for some reason selecting windows boot manager in grub menu sends me to black screen.